# Можно-ли совмещать public domain с другими лицензиями

Tags: лицензирование

Если я пишу библиотеку, которая зависит от библиотек с различными лицензиями (*например MIT или GPL*), могу-ли я выложить свою библиотеку как Public Domain?

Comment: С MIT точно можно, т.к. она никак не ограничивает лицензию **вашего** проекта. С GPL из-за вирусности лицензии могут быть проблемы, см. https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/4349.